# Can i start mining with ANT MINER?

Tags: mining-profitability, mining-hardware, hashpower

from here at little time, i'll get a ANT MINER to start mining bitcoins, and i want to know if i have some chance to get some coins with him.

Brand: ANT MINER

Model: BTC_1.6Gh/s

Overclock: 2.2 Gh/s

I choose ANT MINER because is cheap and i won't take risks buying something expensive that i don't know if i'll use for long time.

Power costs isn't applied, but i just want to know if i can make any money with it, and aproximately time that i'll take.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can plug your specs into a bitcoin calculator like this one http://bitcoinwisdom.com/bitcoin/calculator but since you have such a low hash rate you shouldn't expect much since the difficulty will continue to keep rising.

Comment: I'm having problems trying complete the form in left bar, can you tell me how i complete the form with ANTMINER specs ?

Comment: If you aren't counting electricity costs then you would put 0 in for electricity price and power watts. If you want to account for how much you bought it for you can put that in hardware price. Your choice for pool fee (varies everywhere). Hash rate you would put 2.2 since it is in GH/s

Comment: Always returns a negative valor in "Return" row that can  mean that i have no any profit even without energy costs *-* is it right ? Or if not please calculate for me, i'm asking you. i'm waiting do some coin with this miner

Comment: The most you can expect until there is no longer any point in mining with it would be a little under 0.02 btc and that would run for over a year

Comment: Alright, then what you recommend for a low cost of investment and, a little but considerable profit ?

Comment: I'm not sure that btc mining would be profitable unless you have a few thousand to invest. You could look at scrypt mining but ASICS are coming out now/soon so that would be the same scenario as btc mining. You could just buy some bitcoin instead, it'll be faster and potentially save you money